# Crystal Reports Using IF in SQL Expression Field

Tags: sql, oracle, crystal-reports

I have just started using Crystal Reports and I am trying to set the value of a field to be value1, or value2 instead if that is null. I tried entering this in the text section in the SQL Expression Editor:

```
If IsNull({TABLE.Value1}) Then
{NewField} = (select Value2
    from TABLE where ID = {TABLE.ID})
Else
{NewField} = (select Value1
    from TABLE where ID = {TABLE.ID})
```

But I get an error stating that:

> ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected

How can I get this to work please?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Crystal Reports, but should this be valid Oracle SQL plus some curly-bracket syntax for CR field references? If so, there's no `IsNull` in Oracle, and I'm not sure the `If...Else` syntax is what you want.

Comment: SQL expression in Crystal requires a valid SQL statement

Comment: Can you please tell me these table.Value1 and table.Value2 are available in your dataset bound with that report?

Comment: on crystal report itself >> right click on the filed you want to change>> select display string and add your formula there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually got it working with:

```
If IsNull({TABLE.Value1}) or {TABLE.Value1} = "" then
    {TABLE.Value2}
else
    {TABLE.Value1}
```